# Is it possible to get the parent instance type to a class that is a member variable of it?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I have a class say Parent which has a Selector class as a member variable.  I'd like for the Selector class to select one of many children classes based on what its parent instance is. So maybe if Parent is of type A, then Selector will choose class a, if Parent is of type B, Selector will choose class b, etc.  I also don't want to be passing additional information to the Selector class's choosing function as an argument.  Is there a way to implement this in Java?

```
@Inject
public class Parent {
    private Selector mSelector;
    ...
}

@Inject
public class Selector {
    ...
    public Child chooseChild() {
        // Choose child class based on Parent instance
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, a Java object has no knowledge of any other objects that hold references to it. You'll at least need to tell `Selector` which instance of `Parent` you want to use in `chooseChild()`. You don't have to do it in the method signature itself, but that information has to be available to `Selector` somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Because what you expect to happened if

```
@Inject
public class Parent1 {
    private Selector mSelector;
}
@Inject
public class Parent2 {
    private Selector mSelector;
}
```

and `mSelector` the same?

You can actually scan all beans in context, check if they have field with type `Selector` and get list of *all* beans that match your criterion.

How to do it depends on what `IOC` framework you use.